# View System Output from already running process on Linux

Tags: linux, process, terminal

I started a process on my Linux machine through Putty by running a jar. Now the program will take at least 24 hours to run, and my Putty terminal session has been interrupted. I have added code in the program to output information to track the progress of the job via System.out.println. If I know the PID of the process, is there any way to open a new terminal session in Putty and view the output the process is currently outputting, as if I were in the same session from which I executed the JAR?

Thanks,

Comment: For future reference, I would just redirect the output to a text file for something like this.

Comment: `strace -p PID` would be a crude way to find out what it's currently printing. For future reference... run `screen` when you log in via ssh, then if you get disconnected you can log in and run `screen -r` to pick up where you left off.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach your process to a new terminal like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr.git
cd reptyr/
make
```

And `grep` for you JAR PID:

```
ps -ef | grep "YOUR_JAR"
```

Then :

```
./reptyr YOUR_JAR_PID
```

And you'll see that the current session will be attached to your JAR.

More on this great tool : http://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/